# Java AlphaComposite blending massive quality loss

Tags: java, bufferedimage, java-2d, alphablending

I'm working with timelapse photography and was trying to implement a script to smooth out the transitions by blending multiple photos to one frame. Like photos 1 through 30 yielding frame 1, photos 2 through 31 yielding frame 2 and so on.

When I tried merging 30 consecutive photographs with the GIMP the result was super smooth; when I implement the same logic with Java BufferedImages and AlphaComposite I'm getting what seem to be unacceptable compression artifacts.

I already tried different things, like replacing ImageIO.write() with a compression free ImageWriter, but the result is almost identical. Now I'm out of ideas. Could it be that the AlphaComposite blending causes the quality loss?

[GIMP generated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjqnU.jpg)

[Java generated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GK9Do.jpg)

```java
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class SimplePhotoBlender {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        if (args.length < 1)
            System.out.println("Usage: java SimplePhotoBlender <PATH_TO_IMAGE_FOLDER>");
        else
            new SimplePhotoBlender(args[0]);
    }

    public SimplePhotoBlender(String path) throws IOException {
        // Get all images in folder
        List<File> fileList = getFilesInFolder(new File(path));
        Collections.sort(fileList);

        // Iterate through the list ...
        for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {

            File originalImage = fileList.get(i);
            BufferedImage blended = ImageIO.read(originalImage);

            // ... and blend it with the following 30 images.
            for (int j = 1; j <= 30 && i + j < fileList.size() - 1; j++)
                blended = blend(blended, ImageIO.read(fileList.get(i + j)), 0.9);

            // Finally, save it in a new file.
            File blendedFile = new File(originalImage.getParent() + "/blended/" + originalImage.getName());
            blendedFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            blendedFile.createNewFile();

            // I double-checked but the JPG compression in ImageIO.write()
            // doesn't account for the tremendous amount of quality loss.
            ImageIO.write(blended, "jpg", blendedFile);
        }
    }

    // Needless to say that I copied this from the sources like
    // http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1245201&seqNum=2
    private BufferedImage blend(BufferedImage bi1, BufferedImage bi2, double weight) {

        BufferedImage bi3 = new BufferedImage(bi1.getWidth(), bi1.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = bi3.createGraphics();
        g2d.drawImage(bi1, null, 0, 0);
        g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, (float) (1.0 - weight)));
        g2d.drawImage(bi2, null, 0, 0);
        g2d.dispose();

        return bi3;
    }

    public List<File> getFilesInFolder(final File folder) {
        List<File> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles())
            if (!fileEntry.isDirectory())
                fileNames.add(fileEntry);
        return fileNames;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try options like: setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
setCompressionQuality(0.85f);

Comment: Yeah, together with `ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg").next()` instead of `ImageIO.write(...)`. No Luck.

Comment: From the `AlphaComposite` documentation: _"The accuracy of the results depends on the manner in which pixels are stored in the destination. An image format that provides at least 8 bits of storage per color and alpha component is at least adequate for use as a destination for a sequence of **a few to a dozen** compositing operations."_ Since 30 is more than a dozen, it looks like this might be a problem in the Java graphics, and you'll have to roll your own blending function (not that hard).

Comment: 1: Try writing the image using a non-lossy format (TIFF, PNG, BMP), just to rule out JPEG compression artifacts. 2: Inspired by @Chris' reading of the fine print, try creating a destination image in 16 bit/sample for the compositing, and sample down to 8 bit before writing, to see if this helps.